# Create a new variable as a sequence of two existing variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to import an existing format catalog (the numerical ones for the start) from SAS into R. In SAS formats are organized as a starting value to and end value. All integer-values between should be transformed to the target-value (which can be a number or a character).

To use this in R I have to create a new variable which is the result of the sequences of two numerical variables.

An example dataset looks like this:

```
fname <- c("aformat", "aformat", "aformat", "aformat", "aformat")
svalue <- c(1, 10, 15, 16, 30)
evalue <- c(2, 13, 15, 16, 35)
gvalue <- c("Berne", "Lucerne", "Zurich", "Chur", "Basel")

df <- data.frame(fname, svalue, evalue, gvalue)
```

I tried to solve the problem with the tidyR-Functions "complete" and "fill", but this also fills the gaps between the sequences of the two variables (for example the value 14 which lies between the sequence of 10:13 and 15:15).

Failed try with complete and fill

```
output <- df %>%
      group_by(fname) %>%
         complete(evalue = full_seq(min(svalue):max(evalue), 1)) %>%
            select(fname, evalue, gvalue) %>%
               fill(gvalue, .direction = "up")
```

Comment: Can you please add expected output to your question?

Comment: So the suggested solutions will only work for integer ranges.  Are those the only types of formats you need to deal with?  SAS formats work for floating point values. So a range from 0 to 0.15 could decode to 'LOW' and 0.15 to 5.5 as 'MIDDLE' etc.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, currently I am only "translating" the integer-Formats into R. Next step will be character-Formats and the maybe also the floating point values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reframe` to "expand" rows of a dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

reframe(df, evalue = seq(svalue, evalue), .by = c(fname, gvalue))

     fname  gvalue evalue
1  aformat   Berne      1
2  aformat   Berne      2
3  aformat Lucerne     10
4  aformat Lucerne     11
5  aformat Lucerne     12
6  aformat Lucerne     13
7  aformat  Zurich     15
8  aformat    Chur     16
9  aformat   Basel     30
10 aformat   Basel     31
11 aformat   Basel     32
12 aformat   Basel     33
13 aformat   Basel     34
14 aformat   Basel     35
```

Comment: This works and seems to be equivalent to: ab <- df %>% group_by(fname, gvalue) %>%  reframe(evalue = seq(svalue, evalue))

Comment: Yes, `.by` is introduced in dplyr version 1.1 to aid `group_by` :)

Comment: Interestingly I had some problems (only with some of the formats) with this solution: The  solution that works for all formats is the following:                            newdf <- df %>%
            rowwise() %>%
               mutate(avalue = list(seq(svalue, evalue))) %>%
                  unnest(avalue)

Answer (score 0):

benson gave you the best answer, but I'll provide a version following your general approach just so you can compare it with what you had.

```
fname <- c("aformat", "aformat", "aformat", "aformat", "aformat")
svalue <- c(1, 10, 15, 16, 30)
evalue <- c(2, 13, 15, 16, 35)
gvalue <- c("Berne", "Lucerne", "Zurich", "Chur", "Basel")

df <- data.frame(fname, svalue, evalue, gvalue)

library(tidyverse)

output <- df |>
  group_by(fname,gvalue) |>
  complete(evalue = full_seq(min(svalue):max(evalue), 1)) |>
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(fname,evalue) |> 
  select(fname, evalue, gvalue) |>
  fill(gvalue, .direction = "up")
```

```
   fname   evalue gvalue 
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  
 1 aformat      1 Berne  
 2 aformat      2 Berne  
 3 aformat     10 Lucerne
 4 aformat     11 Lucerne
 5 aformat     12 Lucerne
 6 aformat     13 Lucerne
 7 aformat     15 Zurich 
 8 aformat     16 Chur   
 9 aformat     30 Basel  
10 aformat     31 Basel  
11 aformat     32 Basel  
12 aformat     33 Basel  
13 aformat     34 Basel  
14 aformat     35 Basel
```